# How can I scroll multiple frames in canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a list of frames with further features like a button, label e.g.. but my issues are the size of the LabelFrame. If I put the LabelFrame in container it fits like I want to but it isn't scrollable any more. Any ideas?

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


for i in range(50):
    lf = ttk.Frame(scrollable_frame, text=i).grid(column=1, row=i)

    frame_ip = tk.LabelFrame(lf, bg="white", text=i)
    frame_ip.place(relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.2, relx=0.025, rely=0)
    button_scroll1 = tk.Button(frame_ip, text="Start", bg="grey")
    button_scroll1.place(relwidth=0.15, relx=0.025, relheight=0.15, rely=0.1)

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I put a `Label` inside your `LabelFrame`s and everything seems to work.

Comment: @Derek maybe I'm not clear enough. I try to put another frame and a button in that  LabelFrame. I have added the code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated code with a `Button`, `Canvas` and `Scrollbar` inserted into each `LabelFrame` with grid manager.

I've also made the `container` resizable with row|column configure.

Seems to work fine.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

root.geometry("341x448")

container = ttk.Frame(root)
container.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
container.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient = tk.VERTICAL, command = canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = scrollable_frame, anchor = tk.NW)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)

for i in range(15):
    L = ttk.LabelFrame(scrollable_frame, text = "Sample scrolling label")
    L.grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

    B = ttk.Button( L, text = f"Button {i}")
    B.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NW)
    K = tk.Canvas(
        L, width = 300, height = 100,
        scrollregion = "0 0 400 400", background = "#ffffff")
    K.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
    S = ttk.Scrollbar( L, command = K.yview)
    S.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)
    K["yscrollcommand"] = S.set

container.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NS)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful. 
One further question. It's possible to add something like `canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)` to fit that to the container Frame?

Comment: Canvas is already grid managed but you can always change managers.

Comment: don't mix pack and grid in the same master window, i got it!

Comment: You got it!  I'll make a slight change to my answer that will be closer to your question. Instead of Labels and Buttons I'll replace it with Canvas, Button and Scrollbar. It should look exactly like your image.

Comment: You should post your question to the community as a new question, that way you'll have many eyes on your problem.